# So, how are basic classes written these days in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, class-design, move-semantics, rvalue

*Update: I use MSVC10, which doesn't not give me default move-semantics*

Let's say I want to create a regular class with a couple of non-pod members;

```
class Foo {
NonPodTypeA a_;
NonPodTypeB b_;
}
```

As usual I implement a copy-constructor, and an assignment operator in which I utilize the copy-constructor:

```
Foo(const Foo& other) : a_(other.a_), b_(other.b_) {}
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) { 
  Foo constructed(other);
  *this = std::move(constructed);
  return *this;
}
```

Then I implement the move-constructor and move-assignment, which utilizes std::swap instead of std::move for all member's as they might be written before move-semantics were available, as move-semantics is implemented, I can omit implementing a swap member function:

```
Foo(Foo&& other) {
  ::std::swap(a_, other._a);
  ::std::swap(b_, other._b);
}
Foo& operator=(Foo&& other) { 
  ::std::swap(a_, other._a);
  ::std::swap(b_, other._b);
  return *this;
}
```

And here goes my question; **can something here be done more general, assuming I don't know anything about the members?**

For example, the move-constructor is not compatible with const declared members, but if I implement the move constructor as `Foo(Foo&& other) : a_(std::move(other.a_)), b_(std::move(other.b_)){}` I cant be sure classes without move-semantics are not copied?
Can I utilize the move-constructor in the move-assignment in some clever way?

Comment: As usual, you implement nothing.  Let a_ and b_ take care of themselves.

Comment: There's more wrong with this than right. Among other things, don't fully qualify `std::swap`.

Comment: ADL should be used to invoke `swap`, not explicit qualification (unless that qualification is `boost::swap`, which will use ADL internally).

Comment: ildjarn: I still don't get it, if move-semantics is implemented in the class, std::swap will utilize it (at least in MSVC10)

Comment: And if the data types have a custom swap, you don't _want_ to call `std::swap`, you want to call the custom one.

Comment: ildjarn: When datatypes have a swap member function, I assume std::swap is overloaded for that type

Comment: @ViktorSehr: You're not allowed to add overloads to `namespace std`. That's why you want to pick the `swap` from the ADL namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Erm, do *nothing*. All those things are generated automatically for you<sup>1</sup>. The only time you need to write them by hand is when the class handles resources (and then you need to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)). This is also exactly how it was before. The only difference now is that *after* you considered the Rule of Three you may want to implement the move members either for semantic (i.e. making move-only objects) or performance (moves are usually faster than copies) reasons.

---

<sub>1. MSVC 10 doesn't generate move constructors automatically. In that case you may want to write the move members yourself :(</sub>

Comment: "*MSVC 10 doesn't generate move constructors automatically, but that's a missing feature that will be added in MSVC 11.*" This is not my understanding. Do you have a link handy verifying this?

Comment: It's not going to be added in VC11. Think more along the lines of VC 11.1.

Comment: @ildjarn oops, I got confused. It seems it's not in VC11 after all :( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Given the limitations of MSVC10 and MSVC11 in that you have to write your own move constructors/move assignment operators the following is what I have. I based it on this video by Stephan T. Lavavej

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n

```
class Foo 
{
public:

    //Note: don't pass param by reference. Unified assignment operator
    Foo& operator=(Foo other)
    {
        other.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    Foo(Foo&& other)
      : a_(std::move(other.a_),
        b_(std::move(other.b_){}

    Foo(Foo& other)
      : a_(other.a_),
        b_(other.b_){}

private:
    void swap(Foo& other)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a_, other.a_);
        swap(b_, other.b_);
    }

private:
    NonPodTypeA a_;
    NonPodTypeB b_;
};
```